# Adding Button to TabPanel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to add regular Sencha button to TabPanel in Sencha Touch 2

Sencha Fiddle http://www.senchafiddle.com/#tRd76

Code:

```
//define the application
Ext.application({

    launch: function() {
        addTabPanel();

    }
});

function addTabPanel(){
     Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBar:{
           dockedItems:[{
               xtype: 'button',
               ui: 'round', 
               text: 'Button1',
               dock: 'left',
               handler: function(){
                   alert('Botton1 Working Now');    
               }
           }]
        },

        items:[
            {
            title: 'All Market',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home',

        },

        {
                title: 'Favorite',
                iconCls: 'favorites',
                html:'Favorite',
                itemTpl: '{mwRow}',
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

When Adding Button1 to TabPanel button is not shown.
Why Button1 is not Showing ?

Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do it. I'm not sure there is another way...

```
Ext.application({

    launch: function() {
        addTabPanel();
        var tp = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tabpanel')[0];
        var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
            width:80,
            height:30,
            text:'BTN',
            style:'position:absolute;top:auto;bottom:13px;left:5px;z-index:10;'
        });
        tp.element.insertFirst(btn.element);

    }
});

function addTabPanel(){
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBar:{
            dockedItems:[{
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'round', 
                text: 'Button1',
                dock: 'left',
                handler: function(){
                    alert('Botton1 Working Now');    
                }
            }]
        },

        items:[
            {
                title: 'All Market',
                iconCls: 'home',
                html: 'Home',

            },

            {
                title: 'Favorite',
                iconCls: 'favorites',
                html:'Favorite',
                itemTpl: '{mwRow}',
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Here's the fiddle : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#HvTek

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to add Button in the left side of TabBar without adding new Tab

Comment: It's not native method to add this button but it's working great, I want to thank you very much.

Comment: Only there is something, how to set style of button same as style of regular TabPanel buttons.

Comment: Add a class the the button and play with the CSS

Comment: Wow! Was looking for this too and see solutions with adding dockedItems but that does not work for me. This solution works!

Answer (score -3):

put code snippet into Home item, something like this,

```
....
items:[
        {
        title: 'All Market',
        iconCls: 'home',
        html: 'Home',
        items: [
          {
           xtype: 'button',
           ui: 'round', 
           text: 'Button1',
           dock: 'left',
           handler: function(){
               alert('Botton1 Working Now');    
           }
          }
        ],
},
...
```

[image]

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I want to add Button1 in TabPanel near All Market & Fav icons.

Comment: Hey please pay attention, this not a Toolbar if you want add button. Please look at API Docs http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api.

Comment: Thanks,
I know it's not a Tool Bar, I want to add buttons to this TabBar.
I don't know what do you mean "Look at API Docs"

Comment: @hekomobile It doesn't matter if it's a toolbar or not. It all HTML so it actually is possible (but no very easy) to add an Ext.Button in the tabbar. Sencha just didn't implement anything for that in the framework.

Comment: This answer clearly does not add a button in toolbar. @TDeBailleul answer does add a button in the toolbar.